# How to build a command to filter an interval using -grep on Linux

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-unitig0655   97.872  47  1   0   1   47  121009  120963  2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-unitig0549  97.872  47  1   0   1   47  623680  623726  2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-unitig0278  97.872  47  1   0   1   47  1224581 1224627 2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-Chr4    97.872  47  1   0   1   47  8416368 8416414 2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-Chr4    97.872  47  1   0   1   47  20041035    20041081    2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-Chr4    97.872  47  1   0   1   47  35175472    35175426    2.90e-14    80.6
NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:28960-29007   NG-1DRT-Chr4    97.872  47  1   0   1   47  56460095    56460049    2.90e-14    80.6
```

I need to filter the lines in the range of 0-3900000, considering only the numbers before NG.

`grep 'NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:[0-3900000]' NG.1DRT-blast.out > chr1-blast-NG.txt`

I tried this code, but it returned all the lines with `NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000`, not considering the range.

Anyone knows how to build a proper code for it?

Comment: Is `28960-` always a constant value?

Comment: @anubhava nope, it changes. ```NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:``` it is a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

`awk ' match($0,/NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+NG/,arr) && int(arr[1] arr[2])<=3900000' Input_file`

***OR***

`awk 'match($0,/NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+NG/,arr) && (arr[1] arr[2])+0<=3900000' Input_file`

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here, where using regex like: `NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+NG` where its creating 2 capturing groups whose values are further getting stored into array named arr. Then addition to `match` adding an AND condition if value of digits(by removing `-` between them) is lesser OR equals to  3900000 then print that line.

Comment: Actually, using your command the output is returning blank. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini, ohh this code has worked fine for me. Is your file is same as shown one?

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini, if file is exactly same then you can see 2 things here. 1st: check if your file has control M characters or not by running a command like: `cat -v your_file` if you see control M there then it's an issue. 2nd: check your `awk` commands version by running this: `awk --vsrsion` check both these things and get back to me. It's late night here but I will try my best to help today or if it's late from your side then tomorrow 

Comment: There are no ctrl M characters and the awk version is 5.0.1. I think it worked for you because the sample I'm using here is smaller than 3900000, so it is returning everything anyways. My real sample is way bigger than that.

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini, you could try changing conditions from <= to >= once?

Comment: now I got everything, even above 3900000

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini, so could you please confirm that you are running command `awk 'match($0,/NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+NG/,arr) && (arr[1] arr[2])+0<=3900000' Input_file` only? Here +0 is very important just want to mention here, kindly do let me know

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini, OR if you are using my exact command mentioned in my answer and its not working then try running this one once: `awk 'match($0,/NK.Chr1:75500000-95000000:([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+NG/,arr) && int(arr[1] arr[2])<=3900000' Input_file` I changed it a bit to make those values as integer and then comparing them, let me know how it goes.